# Constructor Initializer list vs initializing in constructor’s body

Tags: c++, constructor

Why is constructor initializer lists faster and easier to use rather than assigning the variable inside the constructor’s body.

Comment: Members are default initialized and then copy constructed when assigning inside ctor's body.

Comment: Related: [Why should I prefer to use member initialization lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/926752)